# Swiftmailer does not send from Hyper-V virtual machine

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, hyper-v

A Hyper-V machine with Ubuntu 18 has a Symfony 4.3 app with SwiftMailer. Attempts to send an email from the command line with `php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send` result in

> [OK] 1 emails were successfully sent.

although mail.log contains this

> localhost sm-mta[5847]: xBBFThub005847: localhost [127.0.0.1] did not
>   issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA-v4

and the email is never received.

`.env.local` contains

```
MAILER_URL=gmail://username@gmail.com:password@localhost?encryption=tls&auth_mode=oauth
```

`.../config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml`:

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: memory
    mailers:
        memory:
            sender_address: 'admin@bogus.info'
            transport:        smtp
            spool: { type: 'memory' }
        spooler:
                sender_address: 'admin@bogus.info'
                transport:        smtp
                spool:
                    type: file
                    path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/spool'
```

Using the identical configuration from the host DOES deliver mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the eventual solution may be excessive it is effective. I first tried installing sendmail but that went nowhere. Purged it and installed postfix following [this tutorial](https://kifarunix.com/configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-smtp-on-ubuntu-18-04/) on using postfix to relay to gmail. When a test message failed I followed the answer provide by kjones at [this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405058/postfix-start-error-port-25-address-already-in-use). Allowed "Access for less secure apps setting" at gmail and all is now well.

All this for a practice go-live run!